# Php to get all printer names-list connected to system

Tags: php

How to get all device printer names connected to the system in network using php? I tried the following code.

```
<?php
$getprt=printer_list(PRINTER_ENUM_LOCAL| PRINTER_ENUM_SHARED );
$printers = serialize($getprt);
$printers=unserialize($printers);
//print_r($printers);
echo '<select name="printers">';
foreach ($printers as $PrintDest)
    echo "<option value=".$PrintDest["NAME"].">".explode(",",$PrintDest["DESCRIPTION"])[1]."</option>";
echo '</select>';
?>
```

I got a fatal error: Call to undefined function printer_list() in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\getprinter.php on line 2

Comment: Where did you get the "printer_list()" function ?

Comment: http://us2.php.net/manual/bg/function.printer-list.php.Is there any solution

Comment: this link doesnt work.

Comment: ya..but I got answer already.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved my issue.Problem was with my php_printer.dll.Once I copied right version of php_printer.dll compatible with PHP Version 5.6.14,started working.

php_printer.dll copied into ext folder.and edited php.ini.

Comment: How did you find the correct php_printer.dll version? Can you link the website?

Answer (score -1):

You can follow this tutorial :

http://basic-programming-tips.blogspot.ch/2013/07/php-phpprinterdll-installation-and.html

Goto Xammp Home directory (ex C:\Xampp)

1. Then open php folder
2. Then open php.ini file.
3. Find ;extension=php_printer.dll
4. Then Remove ";"
5. Done

This restart your server and it should works.

PS : If you don't have php_printer.dll => https://github.com/maryo/php-5.5-windows-extensions/tree/master/php_printer-0.1.0-dev-5.5-vc11-x86

Comment: Actually,<;extension=php_printer.dll > is missing in php.ini

Comment: So you have to search on google to download and install it before adding to php.ini
https://github.com/maryo/php-5.5-windows-extensions/tree/master/php_printer-0.1.0-dev-5.5-vc11-x86

Answer (score -1):

You can get list of connected printers to your system by using exec().

```
    if (PHP_OS_FAMILY === 'Windows') {
        exec('wmic printer list brief', $printers_arr);
    }else{
        exec('lpstat -p', $printers_arr);
    }
    return $printers_arr;
```